# Typescript is complaining about ternary operator

Tags: reactjs, typescript, conditional-operator

I have a simple function in component:

```
const Button = ({text}: Props) => {
const {t, ready} = useTranslation();
const [title, setTitle] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    if (ready) {
      const btnText = text?.length > 0 ? text : 'button.default_text';
      setTitle(btnText);
    }
  }, [ready]);

return <button>{t(title)}</button>
}

interface Props{
text?: string;
}
```

After switching on `strictNullChecks`, typescript started complaining about `'text.length' is possibly 'undefined'.` Yes, because `text` is optional prop `text.length` could be `undefined`, but I'm using a ternary operator.
When checked in console I got:

```
undefined.length > 0
VM904:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at <anonymous>:1:11
```

While with ternary:

```
undefined?.length > 0
false
```

Which means that in both cases expression will be either `true` or `false`. Why typescript complains and is it possible to fix it without using old school `text && text.length > 0` ?

Comment: That's the entire purpose behind `strictNullChecks`, you're saying that you'll guarantee the existence of something before acting upon it, or accessing something within it. It's pretty laid out in the documentation regarding this;

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide a default empty array in cases where `text` is undefined by using `(text ?? []).length > 0 ?`.
Why are you opposed to using `text && text.length > 0 ?` ?  This works too.

Comment: The reason why I didn't like it, is because ternary was doing same thing but shorter, code looked less messy as well. On top of that I just don't see a reason for Typescript to complain, since from tests above could be seen that it won't break even when `undefined`.

Comment: I think your are misunderstanding what typescript is doing for you here. It is not checking if your ternary will succeed, it is checking the type of `text` and that you can read the `length` property of `text` Since `undefined` has no length property it will fail. Hence the error.   This was correctly pointed out by @Jesse

Answer (score -1):

What you are referring to is called Optional Chaining.
What you need though is called the non-null assertion operator, the exclamation point:
`undefined!.length > 0`

Comment: `undefined!.length` is a runtime TypeeError with or without the non-nullish assertion. Moreover, this is why they used optional chaining - to avoid it.